# how can i show applybatch() operation with progressbar?

Tags: android

I am trying to change some contacts phone number with `applyBatch()`.
how can i use progress bar to show operation?
i try this code but it doesn't work!

```
try
{
      getApplicationContext().getContentResolver().applyBatch(ContactsContract.AUTHORITY, ops);
      pr = pr + 1 ;
      myprog.setProgress(pr);
}
catch (Exception e)
{
      e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`applyBatch` is a blocking operation, when it returns it's 100% done. What you want is to do this in another thread, you can use AsyncTask for this, and show indeterminate progress.